# Instantiating some cubes in a simple scene at random positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C#, and I am building a Braitenberg vehicle simulation on unity3D. I am creating an enviroment, random positioned cubes.

Problem 1: it is creating double the ammount of cubes I inserted to create.

Problem 2: I am having trouble to make the vehicles to avoid the cubes. I started by trying to print a message in the console as the vehicle is nearby a cube, but it doesn't work.

here is the code that I have for creating the cubes.

```
public class Cubes : MonoBehaviour {
public float distance;
public List<GameObject> allCubes = new List<GameObject>();
public float[,] positionS = new float[10, 2];
void Start () {
    GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        positionS[x, 0] = Random.Range(-20F, 20F);
        positionS[x, 1] = Random.Range(-20F, 20F);

        //cube.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
        //cube.transform.position = new Vector3(position[x,0], position[x,1], 0.5F);

        allCubes.Add((GameObject)Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(positionS[x, 0], 0.5F, positionS[x, 1]), Quaternion.identity));  
    }
}
```

}

and here is where I check the distances between vehicles:

```
public class CubeDetector: Cubes
{
public float[] distances;
public CarBehaviour car;
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allCubes.Count; i++)
    {
        distances[i] = Vector3.Distance(car.transform.position, allCubes[i].transform.position);

        if (i < 9)
        {
            if (distances[i] < distances[i++])
            {
                Console.WriteLine('y');
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine('n');
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any help is welcomed!

Comment: you have many problems, class names MUST be capitalized, so Cubes, CubeDetector.

Comment: Thanks, as I said, I am a begginer in C#. You said I have many errors, so, apart from the one you just wrote, did you see something else?